# jquery add value and text to li of ul elements from json reponse

Tags: javascript, jquery

We want to **bind json response** to **li** elements with each element having value as id and text as name.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "/api/xyz/",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(response) {
    var items = [];
    $.each(response, function(i, item) {
      items.push('<li</li>",{value:item.id,text:item.name}');
    });
    $('#formFieldCity ul').append(items.join(''));
  }
});
```

But no success, I don't see any binding. Can anyone help?

Comment: What is `data`? Shouldn't be `response`?

Comment: yes, my mistake

Comment: Why do you push items to the array and then append them, when you can just append them right in the `each` function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean

```
     var list = $('#formFieldCity ul'); //caching
     $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "/api/xyz/",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (response) {
            var items = [];
            //Misplaced variable here: data instead of response
            $.each(response, function(i, item) {
                   var mapped = {value:item.id,text:item.name};
                   items.push(mapped)
                   list.append("<li id=\""+item.id+"\">"+item.name+"</li>");

            });
       }
    });
```

This will basically print a json in your HTML. 
Hope I got what you wanted.

EDIT:
If your response is an array, consider using a simple **for** loop, which is about 8x faster then the **jQuery.each**

```
for(var i=0; i<response.length; i++){
    var mapped = {value:response[i].id,text:response[i].name};
    items.push(mapped)
    list.append("<li id=\""+mapped.value+"\">"+mapped.text+"</li>");
}
```

Comment: Ok. Better now?

Comment: @Tony Samperi - You forgot to bind those li elements to the DOM: $('#formFieldCity ul').append(items.join(''));

Comment: I think that `var list = $('#formFieldCity ul');` would be before calling `ajax` function so you don't select same element for every response.

Comment: This displays ""{value:id,text:Name}"" in the <li>. I just want to display text and id to be stored for mapping purpose. Its same way that we do for <option value="Id">Name</option>

Comment: Ok let's add the items array back then...and yes...the caching should be done before the ajax

Comment: Try this: `$('<li />').attr('value', item.id).text(item.name).appendTo(list);`

Comment: It should be ok now...I didn't understand he wanted the id to be the id of the li...

Answer (score 0):

you should write like this:

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
        items.push('<li id="'+item.id+'">'+item.name+'</li>');
    });
```